# how to move mail aliases to other domain

Tags: domain, virtualmin

I have just done the following move, through the virtualmin (4.18) interface:

- moved domain abc.de to old.abc.de
- moved domain new.abc.de to abc.de

The problem that now occurs: all the mail aliases, including mailing lists that existed on the original abc.de now became @old.abc.de making them unavailable through the original address @abc.de

How can I move/change the mail aliases and mailing lists so that they reside under @abc.de instead of @old.abc.de ?

Can I just find/replace the "@old.abc.de" instances in /etc/postfix/virtual with "@abc.de" ?
For example `info@old.abc.de    info-old.abd.de` to `info@abc.de    info-abd.de` ?

Thanks!